# array-like shape (n_samples,) vs [n_samples] in sklearn documents

Tags: scikit-learn, notation

For the sample_weight, the requirement of its shape is array-like shape (n_samples,), sometimes is array-like shape [n_samples]. Does (n_samples,) means 1d array? and [n_samples] means list? Or they're equivalent to each other?
Both forms can be seen here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

Comment: Try calling a method such as `predict(x)` that returns `C : array, shape = [n_samples]`.  Check `type` and `.shape` (if available) on this result, what is that getting you?

Comment: Both are equivalent. The sklearn documentation mentions that objects should be arrays or array-like. Generally, this means a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple example to test this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

#create some data
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

#create the model and fit it
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)

#check the type of some attributes
type(clf.class_prior_)
type(clf.class_count_)

#check the shapes of these attributes
clf.class_prior_.shape
clf.class_count_
```

**Or more advanced searching:**

```
#verify that it is a numpy nd array and NOT a list
isinstance(clf.class_prior_, np.ndarray)
isinstance(clf.class_prior_, list)
```

*Similarly, you can check all the attributes.*

**Results**

```
numpy.ndarray

numpy.ndarray

(2,)

array([ 3.,  3.])

True

False
```

The results indicate that these atributes are **numpy nd arrays**.